# Проверьте, пожалуйста, текст

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите. Здесь есть какие-либо ошибки? Про стилистические оплошности я промолчу.

Ничего не могу посоветовать, потому что считаю, что у каждого свой вкус. И чтобы найти то, что тебе понравится, следует перечитать немало книг. Но есть один выход - читать книги по тематике, которая интересует. Причём неважно какой. Более ведь зависит от того, как вы относитесь к книгам: как к развлечению или способу самообразования. Смотря на ваши предпочтения и на то для чего вы используете книги, можно её выбирать. Это же достаточно очевидные вещи. Сам же читаю классику, книги по истории, философии и некоторую специализированную литературу. А также люблю писателей-экзистенциалистов.

Comment: По-моему, вам стоит переделать этот текст. Слишком запутанно, читается нелегко.

Answer (score 2):

*Причём неважно **по** какой.*

*Более ведь зависит от того, как вы относитесь к книгам...* Я бы сказал: "Выбор зависит от того..." А то так непонятно, что зависит и более, чем что.

*Смотря на ваши предпочтения и на то для чего вы используете книги, можно её выбирать.* Лучше так: "В зависимости от ваших предпочтений и того, для чего вы используете книги, можно её выбирать". Выражения *"смотря на"* вообще нет, есть только *"несмотря на".*

*Сам же читаю классику...* Вдруг с бухты-барахты какой-то "сам" появляется! Правильно: *"сам же я"* или *"я же сам".*

*"А также"* лучше соединить с предыдущим предложением и поставить запятую вместо точки.

Comment: *Причём неважно по какой.*  - не не очень нравится этот вариант без запятой. Вроде как этом случае уже не член предложения, а какой-то обрывок самостоятельного предложения. Не знаю, поймут ли... Но то, что вы отметили неудачность исходной фразы, мне нравится.

Comment: Где-то я видел правило (сейчас искал долго, не смог найти), что если в конце стоит только подчинительный союз, то запятая не нужна. Вряд ли предлог что-то меняет. Или она нужна потому что *тематика* подразумевается?

Comment: Есть такое правило, по-другому, конечно оно формулируется... Типа того, что если обстоятельство состоит из оного союзного слова, то это член предложения. Но я о том и сказал, что в варианте с "по" его применимость вызывает сомнение. Именно предлог. Яне настаиваю, это где-то на подкорке.

Comment: Понятно. Интересно всё-таки узнать, правы вы или нет.

Comment: Я не знаю, как вам помочь. Правило-то вы найдете, а вот моё понимание...  Вы простите, если ко мне нет конкретных вопросов, я покину эту тему и ресурс. Технические проблемы и сам не в лучшей форме... Потом отвечу, если что.

Comment: Спасибо хоть за попытку помочь!) Конечно, не буду вас больше отвлекать.

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не могу посоветовать, потому что считаю, что у каждого свой вкус. И чтобы найти то, что может понравиться, следует перечитать немало книг. Но есть один выход - читать книги по тематике, которая интересует, причём неважно какие. Также многое зависит от того, как вы относитесь к книгам - как к развлечению или способу самообразования. Только определившись в этих вопросах, вы сможете выбирать книги, это же достаточно очевидные вещи. Сам же читаю классику, книги по истории, философии и некоторую специализированную литературу. А также люблю писателей-экзистенциалистов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Мне не нравится предложение: "Более ведь зависит от того, как вы
   относитесь к книгам...".
2. Еще пропустили запятую: "...ваши
   предпочтения и на то, для чего вы..." . Да и как-то само предложение
   не звучит. Я бы переделал.
3. Не знаю, что насчет
   "специализированной литературы" -- это надо обращаться к экспертам
   по стилистике, -- но думаю термин "специальная литература" здесь
   выглядит лучше.
4. Последнее предложение я бы внес в перед ним стоящее -- не вижу смысла его выделять; более того, я не вижу в нем смысла вовсе -- Вы же уже указали, что читаете книги по философии. Или Вы обращаете внимание именно на самих личностей?

Answer (score 0):

Причём неважно какой -> Причём неважно, по какой
Более ведь зависит от того -> Ведь более зависит от того
...и на то для чего -> и на ***то,*** для чего

Остальное обсуждаемо, но не критично.